# Simple Linux MySQL GUI Client That Reads UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm an inexperienced MySQL user running Ubuntu and I need to open a database full of Hebrew data. I prefer a GUI and I downloaded MySQL Workbench. Not only is it incredibly confusing for me, but when I finally figured out how to import the database and run a query, the data just comes out like %16%19%22 etc. Apparently that's because it's using Latin encoding.

So my question is, is there a very simple MySQL GUI Front-end that will let me just see the tables and the data in it in Hebrew, and let me simply and easily execute queries containing Hebrew characters?

Comment: `%16%19%22` does not match Hebrew in any encoding I know; is that exactly what you saw?  There are _multiple_ things that _could_ be going wrong.

Comment: Try phpmyadmin.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see how the tables are defined.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked (and answered) on [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082703/mysql-workbench-data-shows-in-gibberish-instead-of-hebrew), but I do think it's a very valid question for our forum.

The correct answer is that you have to issue the following command:

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name'
```

which for your case (from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html)) is

```
SET NAMES 'hebrew' COLLATE 'hebrew_general_ci'
```

If for whatever reason this doesn't work for you, you could install a Hebrew version of Linux on some machine you have lying around?

Comment: It would be better in the long run to work with `utf8mb4` instead of `hebrew`.

Comment: Possibly, but I thought that the OP had looked at that. The `Hebrew` suggestion was based on a GIGO scenario.